# What is the right site to ask about Turkish TV?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about watching Turkish TV over the internet.

What is the right site for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out https://expatriates.stackexchange.com. If this is a lifestyle question (i.e. not too technical), your post may be allowable there.

> #### Expatriates Stack Exchange
>
> *for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis, and for questions surrounding ordinary life, just complicated by your status as an expatriate.*